# Incorrect output when testing for palindromes using Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to identify palindromes using Python, using lists. However, my program always states that the input word is a palindrome, even if it clearly isn't

```py
word = input("Type a word, and I'll tell you if it's a palidrome or not: ")
word = " ".join(word)

new_word = word.split() #forms a list from user-inputted word
print(new_word)

variable = new_word
variable.reverse() #reverses word list 
print(variable)

if variable == new_word:
    print("This is a palidrome")
else:
    print("This is not a palidrome")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `variable == new_word` is always true is that the assignment operator in this case merely creates a new pointer, not a new list.

In other words, `variable = new_word` does *not* make a copy of the list -- it makes `variable` point to the same list in memory.  So when you reverse `variable`, you are actually reversing the original list.  You can see this if you print `new_word` *after* you have run `variable.reverse()`.

[This article](http://scottlobdell.me/2013/08/understanding-python-variables-as-pointers/) is a helpful introduction to pointers, and [this one](https://medium.com/@thawsitt/assignment-vs-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy-in-python-f70c2f0ebd86) is a nice explanation of assignment vs. shallow-copy vs. deep-copy. Since your list is just a list of strings, shallow-copy will do the trick.[1] Deep-copy is overkill, but it works too.

#### Shallow-copy:

```
variable = list(new_word)
```

For Python 3.3 and later, lists have a built-in `copy` method:

```
variable = new_word.copy()
```

Another option is to use slicing, but without supplying a starting or ending index:

```
variable = new_word[:]
```

Finally, the `copy` module supplies a function for creating shallow copies:

```
variable = copy.copy(new_word)
```

#### Deep-copy:

```
import copy
variable = copy.deepcopy(new_word)
```

[1] While [mrtnlrsn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3061838/mrtnlrsn) says you have made a shallow copy, this is not true, as the linked articles explains.

Answer (score 1):

`variable` is a shallow copy of the `new_word` list, so `variable` is also reversed (as it refers to the same list)
.
Try using

```
variable = copy.deepcopy(new_word)
```

Comment: Just adding [copy doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) for completeness

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get the result by reversing the input string also, Use the below code:-

```
word = input("Type a word, and I'll tell you if it's a palidrome or not: ")
new_word = list(reversed(word))  #Reversing the string
new_word = ''.join(new_word)  # Converting list into string

if word == new_word :
    print("This is a palidrome")
else:
    print("This is not a palidrome")
```

**OR**

I have made changes in your code:-

```
word = input("Type a word, and I'll tell you if it's a palidrome or not: ")
word = " ".join(word)

new_word = word.split() #forms a list from user-inputted word
print(new_word)

variable = new_word.copy()   # This is the change I have made.
variable.reverse() #reverses word list 
print(variable)

if variable == new_word:
    print("This is a palidrome")
else:
    print("This is not a palidrome")
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this works while the original one does not?

Comment: @LucasWieloch `variable = new_word
variable.reverse()` when you are making changes in the `variable` it is also making changes in `new_word`. Instead of this you have to use 'variable=new_word.copy()` ,Now you can make changes in `variable` by `variable.reverse()`, it will not make changes in `new_word`.

Comment: Thanks, I initially did the former which is nice and concise

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace

```
variable = new_word
```

with

```
variable = new_word[:]
```

This will make a proper copy of your variable, that you can manipulate independently.